# Why are my subview bounds (0,0,0,0) after setting constraints?

Tags: swift

I am using the latest version of swift and writing everything programmatically. I’m trying to create a UIView *holderView* that resides inside and is constrained to the bounds of the safe area of the top level view. This code returns

```
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

which suggests that the holderView is not constrained to the top level view. Can anyone please advise on how to proceed? Code below.

```
class WelcomeViewCon: UIViewController {
    
    var holderView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        configure()
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        view.addSubview(holderView)
        holderView.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        let constraints = holderView.constraintsForAnchoringTo(boundsOf: view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        print(view.bounds)
        print(holderView.bounds)
    }
}

extension UIView {

    /// Returns a collection of constraints to anchor the bounds of the current view to the given view.
    ///
    /// - Parameter view: The view to anchor to.
    /// - Returns: The layout constraints needed for this constraint.
    func constraintsForAnchoringTo(boundsOf view: UIView) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return [
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tyler That worked, but can you comment on why the bounds of holderView are still (0,0,0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a matter of timing. Constraints do not take effect until after layout. But you are applying constraint *during* layout (which is totally wrong; this is what `updateConstraints` is for, or just do it all once in `viewDidLoad`) and so you cannot measure the results until after the *next* layout.

Moreover layout happens many times so your code adds the subview and the constraints over and over. Dangerous stuff.

Comment: Got it--will switch everything over to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Right but even then you cannot measure in the same place you apply the constraints. They have not taken effect yet!